# Component selection status not preserved on update (install4j)

Tags: install4j

The component selection status is saved in the `response.varfile` file and I have the "Load a response file" action with "Overwrite existing" strategy.

However, on "Installation components" screen default selection is always shown. Should any additional steps be performed to use previous components selection during update?

I am using Install4j 6.1.6

Comment: The mechanism works for me. Do you have any code that sets selection state of installation components explicitly via the API? What is the output in `.install4j/installation.log` after the `[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.LoadResponseFileAction`?

Comment: @IngoKegel Your comment helped me realize that the LoadResponseFileAct‌ion is not being executed. I removed condition expression and it started working.